# How to select the minimum value which includes exponential value for each ID based on the forth column?

Tags: sorting, awk

Can you please tell me how to Select rows with min value, including exponential, based on fourth column and group by first column in linux?

Original file

```
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,0.22
1,a,b,5e-10
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,0.06
2,c,d,0.003
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,0.002
3,e,f,2e-8
3,e,f,1.0
```

The file I want is as below.

```
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,2e-8
```

Actually this worked fine, so thanks for everybody!

```
tail -n +2 original_file > txt sort -t, -k 4g txt | awk -F, '!visited[$1]++' | sort -k2,2 -k3,3 >> final_file
```

Comment: Welcome to SO please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Actually I tried as below. But this does not handle "E-8" or those exponential values. tail -n +2 original_file > txt

sort -t, -k 4n txt | awk -F, '!visited[$1]++' | sort -k2,2 -k3,3 >> final_file

Comment: Thank you for letting know your efforts, kindly do add them in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it fairly easily in `awk` just by keeping the current record with the minimum 4<sup>th</sup> field for a given 1<sup>st</sup> field. You have to handle outputting the header-row and storing the first record to begin the comparison, which you can do by operating on the first record `NR==1` (or first in each file processed, `FNR==1`).

You can store the first minimum in an array indexed by the first field and save the initial record containing values operating on the 2<sup>nd</sup> record. Then it is just a matter of checking if the first-field is not the same as the last, if so output the minimum record for the last and keep going until you run out of records. (**note:** this presumes the first-fields appear in increasing order as they do in your file) Then you use the `END` rule to output the final record.

You can put that together as follows:

```
awk -F, '
    FNR==1 {print; next}
    FNR==2 {rec=$0; m[$1]=$4; next}
    {
        if ($1 in m) {
            if ($4 < m[$1]) {
                rec=$0
                m[$1]=$4
            }
        }
        else {
            print rec
            rec=$0
            m[$1]=$4
        }
    }
END {
    print rec
}' file
```

(where your data is in the file `file`)

If your first field is not in increasing order, then you will need to save the current minimum record in an array as well. (e.g. turn `rec` into an array indexed by the first-field holding the total record as its value). You would then delay looping over both arrays until the `END` rule to output the minimum record for each first-field.

**Example Use/Output**

You can update the filename to match the filename containing your data, and then to test, all you need to do is select-copy the `awk` expression and middle-mouse paste it into an xterm in the directory containing your `file`, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, '
>     FNR==1 {print; next}
>     FNR==2 {rec=$0; m[$1]=$4; next}
>     {
>         if ($1 in m) {
>             if ($4 < m[$1]) {
>                 rec=$0
>                 m[$1]=$4
>             }
>         }
>         else {
>             print rec
>             rec=$0
>             m[$1]=$4
>         }
>     }
> END {
>     print rec
> }' file
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,2e-8
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But this does not read E-8 or E-10. So this handles only the values as below... I think we need to add -g?
```
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,0.22
2,c,d,0.06
2,c,d,0.003
3,e,f,0.002
3,e,f,1.0
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused when you say *"does not read E-8 or E-10"* When I run against your line I get `1,a,b,0.22 2,c,d,0.003 3,e,f,0.002` returned (as it looks like it should be??) Do you mean `"E-8"` alone instead of `1.xxE-8`? Also only one `\`` around text in comments to highlight as code `:)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The original file is as below.
`
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,0.22
1,a,b,5e-10
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,0.06
2,c,d,0.003
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,0.002
3,e,f,2e-8
3,e,f,1.0
`

I tried the codes you taught me, but the results was as below...
`
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,0.22
2,c,d,0.003
3,e,f,0.002
`

I wanted to get the results as below.
`
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,2e-8
`

Comment: If you are on Linux, a quick test is to copy the text in your question, then in a terminal `cat << EOF > datafile` press return and paste the text into the terminal. Then on the 1st blank line type `EOF` and press return. That will create a proper ASCII version of your file to use. Now run the `awk` command against `datafile`. If you are using WSL in Win10 -- that works there too. You cannot save with a windows editor (unless you have changed the default line-endings and chosen UTF-8 as your character set - choosing ASCII is safer)

Comment: See: [how to convert dos windows newline crlf to unix newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script) and [HTML Encoding (Character Sets)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) `em-dash` and `en-dash`. Also [Format-Hex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7) if on windows.

Comment: Run a hexdump program and make sure your `'-'` are not html Unicode dashes (`em-dash` or `en-dash`) instead of ASCII `45 (0x2d)`. Here `awk` will handle the DOS line endings without issue. There is an issue with your data file if you are getting different results. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

A non-`awk` approach, using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -H -f -t, -g1 min 4 < input.txt | cut -d, -f1-4
ID,y,z,p-value
1,a,b,1.2e-10
2,c,d,3e-7
3,e,f,2e-8
```

(The `cut` is needed because with the `-f` option `datamash` adds a fifth column that's a duplicate of the 4th; without it it'll just show the first and fourth column values. Minor annoyance.)

This does require that your data is sorted on the first column like in your sample.