# Find command in a bash script not working

Tags: bash, find, command

I have a bash that reads as input a list of folder names (all numbers not letters) and tries to find the location of each.
The Find command doesn't return anything to me at all. I do not know why. Whereas if I put the raw value without using a variable it works.

Code :

```
    #!/bin/bash
filename='bat.txt'
n=1
while read line;
do
lien=$(find ./ -type d -name "$line")
# for read each line
echo "line no. $n : $line"
n=$((n+1))
done < $filename
```

Bat.txt sample :

```
19223
12233
34434
34434
```

Comment: Please replace all images with its text.

Comment: Done ! Do you have a solution about this ?

Comment: There is a typo: you assign to `lien`, and then access `$line`.

Comment: Your code isn't the same as on the picture. On the picture, you incorrectly escaped `$` and put the `*` between quotes, making `find` try to find directories literally named `*$line*`.

Comment: Even if I do that, it doesn't change the result.                                                 
lien=$(find ./ -type d -name "$line")
# for read each line
echo "line no. $n : $lien"

Comment: What does the directory structure look like?

Comment: Obviously, the directories are not there. On the first iteration, `line`  equals  (according to your example data) `19223`, and you are searching for a directory below your working directory, which has the name `19223`. Since this is not found, I conclude that such a directory does not exist.

Comment: `lien=$(find ./ -type d -name "$line")` should be `line=$(find ./ -type d -name "$line")` for this to work. Also, `#!/bin/bash` should not be indented. Other than that, it works as expected?!

Comment: I tried replacing the $line with 19223 and it happens to find the folder. but when I put the $ line back it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Add the command `set -x` at the beginning of the script (but after the shebang line) to get an execution trace as it runs, and see what that shows.

Comment: @HamzaYOUSSOUF: please post the output of `cat -v bat.txt`. This might be a case of bad line endings.

Comment: @Maxxim Output of  cat -v bat.txt :  5453^M, 6405^M,...

Comment: What is "^M" ? Each line finish with this

Comment: @HamzaYOUSSOUF: As I suspected, the line endings of `bat.txt` are the issue. I added an answer to describe the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on additional information provided via comments, the solution should be to correct the typos in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='bat.txt'
n=1
while read line;
do
line=$(find ./ -type d -name "$line")
# for read each line
echo "line no. $n : $line"
n=$((n+1))
done < $filename
```

and to convert the line endings of `bat.txt` from *Windows/DOS* to *Linux/Unix*:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' bat.txt
```

Additional information on this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings), various alternatives to perform the conversion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script).