# When I type Anything in Ubuntu it returns /usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, bash, ubuntu

When I type Anything in Ubuntu it returns `/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory`

I noticed the issues when I tried making a react app

```
npx create-react-app app_name
```

it returns `/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory`

Then when tried to check the versions of npm or anything else

it returns `/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory`

The only thing that has worked so far is navigating through directories and making new ones.

I don't know what to do. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an executable shell script with a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. But you have likely created it on Microsoft Windows, and the line endings are \r\n (i.e. CRLF), instead of \n (LF) on Linux.

This does not work with shell scripts: you have to change the line endings to \n (Notepad++ can do that, for instance). What happens is, Linux reads lines separated by \n, so the first line ends with bash\r, and this is not the name of a known executable.

Note: this will fail not only with bash, but any script using a shebang: that can be Perl, Python, R, etc. That's because whatever the programming language, the executable is not called, because it's not found.

Note also that those programming languages usually read happily files with \r\n line endings. It's really the shebang line (i.e. executable scripts) that causes this problem.

Comment: I think I understand. I am just unsure of how to do that.  Or how any of that happened in the first place. As far as I know I never messed with any of that.

Comment: @xeromoot You can check the file with hexdump on Linux, to see what line endings actually are. To fix the file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @xeromoot I'm not sure I understand. You don't know why the file got screwed, or you don't know how to fix it? If the latter, then it's precisely what dos2unix does. I can't help much for the former unless you explain precisely how this file is created or edited. It's not a normal behavior for a Linux text file to get CRLF line endings, but in some cases it can happen: if the file editor is configured to use CRLF (can be changed in Eclipse and RStudio for instance), if the file is pulled from git with some configurations of git, etc.

Comment: The reason there are windows line endings is because the Ubuntu shell has some windows folders on the PATH.  Duh.

Comment: @djangofan Might be that, but note that Windows is never mentioned in the question. I have also had the same kind of error on a Linux server, when transferring scripts with CRLF line endings.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice `echo $PATH` shows that windows programs are on your Linux path!   That means your windows NodeJS and NPM might be getting picked up.

Stop Windows path variables being shared with WSL by editing the `/etc/wsl.conf` file in WSL. If the file doesn't exist, execute sudo touch /etc/wsl.conf first. Edit the file with the command sudo nano `/etc/wsl.conf` and add the following configuration:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```

Then restart WSL2 with command `wsl --shutdown` in Windows powershell.